# Spacing Issue Between Chapter Title and Chapter Title Body | Long Chapter Title

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters, titles, titlesec

How do I remove the spacing between Chapter and its name?

```
CHAPTER#

CHAPTER NAME

to 

CHAPTER#
CHAPTER NAME
```

I have tried using

`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \ \thechapter}{-5mm}{}[]`

But, for long titles that will expand to multiple lines the spacing will be inconsistent. You can see the spacing between CHAPTER 1 and LONG CHAPTER THAT WILL CAUSE THIS ISSUE. How do I fix this? And make the content of the title close to the chapter number without inconsistency.
[image]

Here is a **MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} % MATH SYMBOLS
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Font size
\usepackage{titlesec} % Title format
\usepackage{setspace} % setting stretch
\usepackage{geometry} % Paper margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fix page numbering


%================================================================
%         FONT SETTING
%================================================================

\geometry{a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\setstretch{1.15}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\linespread{1.08}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.08}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


%================================================================
%         TITLE SETTING
%================================================================
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \
\thechapter}{-5mm}{}[]
\titleformat{\section}
{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\bf}
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{13}{18.2}\bf}
{\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
%================================================================
%         NAMES IN title/names_super
%================================================================



\begin{document}

\chapter{LONG CHAPTER THAT WILL CAUSE THIS ISSUE}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic: Although this "title" is a dummy, it would look much nicer and make better sense by moving "this" to the next line,  Using a "tie", `THIS~ISSUE`, is almost always the easiest and safest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That vertical space that seems wrong to you is actually correct. What is wrong is the space after "CHAPTER 1". This is partly due to your definition of `\chapter` and partly due to the use of the `parskip` package (or redefining `\parskip` to 8pt).

I used the `fontsize` package to change the normal size and line spacing. By using `fontspec`, however, you can also act differently.

Below is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[skip=8pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Title format
\usepackage{geometry} % Paper margins
\geometry{a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%================================================================
%         FONT SETTING
%================================================================
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \changefontsize[16.2]{12}
%================================================================
%         TITLE SETTING
%================================================================
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{%
  \parskip=0pt
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \
  \thechapter}
  {0mm}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\bf}
  {\thesection.}
  {0.5em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontsize{13}{18.2}\bf}
  {\thesubsection.}
  {0.5em}
  {}
\titlespacing{\section}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0in}{12pt}{8pt}
%================================================================
%         NAMES IN title/names_super
%================================================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{LONG CHAPTER THAT WILL CAUSE THIS ISSUE}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works. But, I want to reduce the spacing more. I have manged to find my way around it by `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{20}{15}\selectfont\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER 
\thechapter}{-3mm}{}[]`

I changed the value in  `\fontsize{}{}` second bracket.